# SQL order by alternating

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to order sql in an alternating way (intersplicing highest and lowest results)

For example, order by year descending results in something like:

```
2016
2015
2014
2013
```

order by year ascending results in something like

```
1990
1991
1992
1993
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
2016
1990
2015
1991
```

There is probably a manual way to do this (i.e. sort and limit then `UNION`the two result sets), but apart from that, does SQL (in my case Postgres) support this natively?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that your table `table_name` that have column name `year_column` (If you have a query, change `table_name` to your query and same to `year_column`)

Then you could use this:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY year_column DESC) rnm_desc,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY year_column ASC) rnm_asc,
    t.*
FROM 
 table_name t   
ORDER BY 
    LEAST(rnm_desc, rnm_asc), 
    year_column DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select      *

from        t

order by    least (row_number () over (order by yr asc),row_number () over (order by yr desc))
           ,yr desc
;
```